# Azure Github Integration with custom domain

Tags: github, azure-web-app-service, webhooks

I want to use github to deploy my webapp on Azure. I setup github on Azure as my deployment source. But since I have a custom domain instead of using the free azurewebsits.net, I think I am having issues seeing the website from github. The webhook on github shows azurewebsites.net.... same on azure. I can edit the webhook on github but can't on Azure. What is the best way to integrate github with azure with a custom domain?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to edit the webhook on github, let it stick with the default sitename.azurewebsites.net.

When you setup a custom domain name, your default domain name (sitename.azurewebsites.net) still keeps working.  Github will use that to deploy to your site

Comment: But now do I get it to my custom domain at example.com instead of of sitename.azurewebistes.net?

Comment: sitename.azurewebistes.net and your custom domain name are both just pointers to your actual site. It doesn't matter which one people use, they both point to the same location. Git hub can use the *.azurewebsites.net url and people visiting your custom domain name will see the changes

Comment: I got it, I had all the same file names from the old and with github. I didn't release azure we saving the website files on the same server. I just had to rename some files and it was good to go.